# Layer 2 gas fees are paid in which cryptocurrency?

Tags: polygon, fees, scalability, layer-2

I have a doubt regarding Layer 2 blockchains (zk, optimistic, ...).
At some point, nodes running L2 blockchains, send transactions to the L1 blockchain (Ethereum for the sake of this example), which means they have to pay transaction fees in L1 native cryptocurrency (ether).

My question is, how are those fees charged to users sending transactions to the L2 blockchain? In the case of Polygon PoS or zkEVM for instance, if I am not mistaken, those fees are paid in MATIC (Polygon's token), however the exchange rate between MATIC and ETHER can change, and nodes submitting transactions to L1 could potentially lose money.....

I am clearly missing something here, could anybody help me out?